# Using Apache-Kafka with Flutter/darts

Tags: flutter, dart, apache-kafka

I am working with Flutter and I need to write data to Kafka. How can I do this in flutter/darts.. Is there a Kafka client that I can use?.

Comment: what do you mean by writing data to kafka ? Posting a message to a topic ? can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Keep in mind that Kafka is a backend technology and Flutter is often frontend. It definitely shouldn't be used on mobile clients

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [`dart-kafka`](https://github.com/dart-kafka/kafka) which is a Kafka client library written in Dart. It provides both Kafka Producers and Consumers but it's been a long time since it was last updated.

Comment: This library uses an older version of dart SDK which does not work with the latest version. A newer client is a dire need!